# Are there any guidelines around which SE site should host a given question/tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, migration, site-recommendation

- I wanted to ask a question about [Paw](http://luckymarmot.com/paw/).
- Their [support link](http://luckymarmot.com/paw/support) says to post questions to Stack Overflow.
- However the [SO tag for Paw](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/paw/info) says to use Apple StackExchange.

Figuring that posting a question on SO would get it closed/moved, I asked a new question on AskDifferent (http://apple.stackexchange.com) and asked someone to create a new tag (which they did).

- Now the question has been [put on hold](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/178912/is-it-possible-to-re-use-headers-in-paw) and I'm being told to [move the question to SO](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/178912/is-it-possible-to-re-use-headers-in-paw#comment212095_178912)

Do I now need to file a question on Meta SO about the `paw` tag there? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Is Paw (the rest client) a tool used by programmers?

Comment: Sounds like lack of research from the side of [PAW leading developer](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1698645/micha-mazaheri), who did not notice the tag is already used for something else. Feel free to contact him and ask to change their support page. New tag should be created first though, e.g. [paw-app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paw-app) but it's really up to their dev team to do that.

Comment: @rene well, it says "ultimate REST client for Mac" on their page so yeah, sounds like a tool for programmers. (not the PAW in the existing tag wiki)

Comment: @rene see my comment edit. :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Ok, so SO _is_ the correct place vs AskDifferent since it's a dev tool. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The question has been migrated and I've created a `paw-app` tag over on SO.

Comment: Cheers, I didn't notice you're high rep member of SO. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone for finding the right answer. I've updated the [support page](http://luckymarmot.com/paw/support), to mention the "paw-app" tag.

Answer (score 2):

If you ask about the Paw application on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for things relating to the app itself (and not REST code) - that's totally fine and welcome. We also welcome questions on Xcode - with one big *caution* being that code-level questions are off-topic on Ask Different.

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

> Code-level programming questions (cocoa, LLVM, etc…) are off-topic here. We do encourage AppleScript, Automator, and UNIX shell scripting questions as well as how to use tools like Xcode for non-language specific tasks.

I won't speak for the other code and programming sites other than to say have a look at their help sections if you're worried about asking on the Apple specific site.

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic
- https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

So if you have problems installing, running, configuring gatekeeper, understanding how the Paw app stores data or is configured, we could be the ideal place for you to ask that.

If you need help with using it to make code changes or things that really are about REST and not the app itself, have a look at Stack Overflow to start. If you ask elsewhere and get closed, feel free to ping me here - comment to the question and I'll do what I can to get it hosted on Ask Different or help you get it reopened or migrated to any site here where it would be proper.

Comment: thanks for the clarification; I did think that since it was an app _feature_ question (i.e. "is it possible to save headers as preset groups") that it would belong there [Ask Different]. However, enough people thought otherwise ("this is a programming tool") to flag and move it so I didn't bother fighting too much :)

Comment: Btw, I've tried to leave several emails to the dev team telling them to update their support link (the `paw` tag on SO is used for something else so I created `paw-app`, but there has been no response).